# Trap SIGTERM from JVM

Tags: java, bash, tomcat

In bash is a useful command `trap`. It intercepts various signals like `SIGKILL`, `SIGHUP` etc to process.

So... We have a problem that **Tomcat** sometimes dies without any visible reasons. And - without any helpful information in log-files.

My idea is add `trap` to its java-analog command to collect `jstack` before **JVM** with **Tomcat** will die.

How can I do it in **Java**? Please note - I'm not Java-programmer.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JVM (Oracle's at least) already installs signal handlers and translates signals into exceptions and other useful things. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/signals.html.

Usually when Tomcat dies without logs, it's a symptom of running out of stack or heap space (Tomcat runs in the same JVM as the web apps, and a misbehaved app can crash the server before the logs are flushed).

What version of Tomcat are you using? If you are using Tomcat 6+, you can disable log buffering completely so that the final messages are flushed as they are written. See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html.

For [JULI](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html#Using_java.util.logging_(default)), a negative bufferSize will force flushes after each write.

Comment: We using 5.5.23 for now and log4j as main logging tool... Thank for tip!

Comment: Time to upgrade. Support for 5.5.x ended some time ago.

Comment: We can't unfortunatelly, for reasons beyond our control..."We have what we have".

Comment: Perhaps you should do some proper debugging. Try and narrow down the causes. Add logging to your applications. Run the apps in a debugger. Create standalone tests. Etc.